# gmock ElementsAreArray() function not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, googletest

I am trying to call the function ElementsAreArray() inside another function. I was using it normally inside my tests, but I wanted to make the tests reports better and organize it on a function. So I created the following files:

**gUnitTest_Test_Array.cpp** where I have my function definition:

```
#include "gUnitTest_Test_Array.h"

void gtest_array::expect_that_size1(volatile signed long arrayA[CIC8_TABLE_SIZE],volatile signed long arrayB[CIC8_TABLE_SIZE], std::string msg1, std::string msg2)
{
    using namespace testing;

            bool HasError = false; 
            EXPECT_THAT(arrayA, ElementsAreArray(arrayB)) << (HasError = true);

            if (HasError)
                std::cout << msg1; 
            else 
                std::cout << msg2;
}
```

**gUnitTest_Test_Array.h** where I have my class declaration:

```
#pragma once
#ifndef GUNITTEST_TEST_ARRAY_H
#define GUNITTEST_TEST_ARRAY_H
#include "gUnitTest_Common_Defs.h"


using namespace std;

class gtest_array
{
public:
    void expect_that_size1(volatile signed long arrayA[CIC8_TABLE_SIZE], volatile signed long arrayB[CIC8_TABLE_SIZE], std::string msg1, std::string msg2);
};


#endif
```

**gUnitTest_Common_Defs.h** where I include necessary libs and definitions

```
#pragma once
//#ifndef GUNITTEST_COMMON_DEFS_H
//#define   GUNITTEST_COMMON_DEFS_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <gmock/gmock.h> 

#define ... //Whatever I need to define
```

Then in my Test file I call the function:

```
std::string msg1 = "failed";
std::string msg2 = "passed";
TestArray1.expect_that_size1(sG_Demodulation_Diagnostics_Buffers.WNLCPF_CIC8_Decim, s32L_CIC8_table, msg1, msg2);
```

The problem is that when I try to compile, the compiler complains that it does not find the function ElemetsAreArray(). which for me does not make sense since I included all the gtest necessary headers and before moving to the function I was using this function inline on my test as below:

```
EXPECT_THAT(sG_Demodulation_Diagnostics_Buffers.WNLCPF_CIC8_Decim, ElementsAreArray(s32L_CIC8_table)) << "The CIC8 block test failed. Failed at index: " << i;
```

**Here are the error messages**

> Error C2672   'testing::ElementsAreArray': no matching overloaded
> function found    GUnitTesting    \GUnitTesting\gUnitTest_Test_Array.cpp  15

> Error C2893   Failed to specialize function template
> 'testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcherContainer::value_type
> testing::ElementsAreArray(const Container
> &)'   GUnitTesting    \GUnitTesting\gUnitTest_Test_Array.cpp  15

> Error C2784   'testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher
> testing::ElementsAreArray(const T (&)[N])': could not deduce template
> argument for 'const T (&)[N]' from 'volatile long
> []'   GUnitTesting    \GUnitTesting\gUnitTest_Test_Array.cpp  15

> Error C2780   'testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher
> testing::ElementsAreArray(const T *,size_t)': expects 2 arguments - 1
> provided  GUnitTesting    \GUnitTesting\gUnitTest_Test_Array.cpp  15

> Error C2780   'testing::internal::ElementsAreArrayMatcher<::std::iterator_traits<_Ty>::value_type>
> testing::ElementsAreArray(Iter,Iter)': expects 2 arguments - 1
> provided  GUnitTesting    \GUnitTesting\gUnitTest_Test_Array.cpp  15

> Error C2672   'testing::internal::MakePredicateFormatterFromMatcher': no
> matching overloaded function
> found GUnitTesting    \GUnitTesting\gUnitTest_Test_Array.cpp  15

> Error C2512   'testing::AssertionResult': no appropriate default
> constructor
> available GUnitTesting    \GUnitTesting\gUnitTest_Test_Array.cpp  15

Comment: The hint: arrayA and arrayB are not arrays as your expect.

Comment: I was about to answer, but I have no knowledge about `volatile` and it appears crucial. As noted in above comment, `arrayA` and `arrayB` are not arrays, they [decayed to pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-to-pointer-decay). However, once you fix it (https://godbolt.org/z/soh6oE), it turns out `ElementsAreArray` converts the data to `std::vector`, and vector doesn't accept `volatile` types. Probably the only option you have is to write your own matcher, which will be simpler and faster than trying to solve this issue.

Comment: I know they are pointers to the first array element and not array. Ok, In that case could I copy the content to a local array in the function and try to call the ElementsAreArray?

Comment: Regarding them being volatile this is no problem, as I was already using ElementsAreArray() with volatile arrays before moving my stuff inside the function.

Comment: Try to make the arguments arrayA and arrayB references to arrays and this must resolve your trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments above were right about arrayA and arrayB not being arrays itself. I knew it, but I thought that ElementsAreArray() would be happy receiving the address from the pointers.
It turns out, as also commented above, that it converts it to std::vectors, so the workaround I found was to create a local copy of my vectors inside the function (if anyone has any more efficient idea, please let me know):

```
#pragma once
//#ifndef GUNITTEST_TEST_ARRAY_H
//#define   GUNITTEST_TEST_ARRAY_H
#include "gUnitTest_Common_Defs.h"


using namespace std;

class gtest_array
{
public:
    void expect_that_size1(volatile signed long (*arrayA), volatile signed long (*arrayB), uint16_t table_size, std::string msg1, std::string msg2);
};


//#endif
```

```
#include "gUnitTest_Test_Array.h"

void gtest_array::expect_that_size1(volatile signed long (*arrayA),volatile signed long (*arrayB), uint16_t table_size, std::string msg1, std::string msg2)
{
    using namespace testing;
    signed long array1[CIC8_TABLE_SIZE];
    signed long array2[CIC8_TABLE_SIZE];

    std::copy(arrayA, arrayA + table_size, array1);
    std::copy(arrayB, arrayB + table_size, array2);

    bool HasError = false; 
    EXPECT_THAT(array1, ElementsAreArray(array2)) << (HasError = true);

    if (HasError)
        std::cout << msg1; 
    else 
        std::cout << msg2;
}
```